How to compute the diffraction efficiency of a thin phase grating with arbitrary groove shape?
From Magnusson and Gaylord (1978), the wave amplitudes, $S_i(z)$, of $p$-polarized light for a thin, arbitrary phase grating are given by the equation
$$
\frac{\partial S_i}{\partial z} + \gamma \sum_{h=1}^\infty(f_h S_{i - h} - f_h^* S_{i + h}) = 0 \qquad \qquad (1)
$$
where $i$ is the diffraction order, $z$ is the normalized thickness coordinate, $\gamma=\pi d n_1 \cos \theta / \lambda$ is the normalized amplitude of the fundamental grating, $d$ is the thickness of the grating, $n_1$ is the index of refraction for the fundamental grating, $\theta$ is the angle of incidence, $f_h = f_{ch} + j f_{sh}$ are the Fourier coefficients describing the grating shape, and $j=\sqrt{-1}$ is the imaginary unit.
To solve this equation we can express the transmittance of the grating in terms of a phase delay,
$$
\tau(x, z) = \exp[- 2 \pi j z d \Delta n \cos\theta / \lambda],
$$
where $\Delta n = n_1 f(\xi)$ is the phase delay of the grating,
$$
f(\xi) = \sum_{h=1}^\infty [f_{ch} \cos(h \xi) + f_{sh} \sin(h \xi)]
$$
is the normalized phase delay, $\xi = K x$ is the normalized coordinate perpendicular to the grooves, $K$ is the grating groove frequency, and $x$ is the physical coordinate perpendicular to the grooves.
The transmittance of the grating can also be expressed in term of the diffracted wave amplitudes,
$$
\tau(x, z) = \sum_{i=-\infty}^\infty S_i(z) \exp(j i \xi),
$$
which are Fourier series coefficients given by
$$
\begin{align}
S_i(z) &= \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_0^{2 \pi} \tau(x, z) \exp(-j i \xi) \, d\xi \\
&= \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_0^{2 \pi} \exp[-2 j \gamma z f(\xi)] \exp(-j i \xi) \, d\xi
\end{align}
$$
and are solutions to the governing differential equation (Equation 1).
I'm trying to find a similar expression for the $s$-polarization mode. From an earlier work (Magnusson and Gaylord 1977) the governing equation becomes
$$
\frac{\partial S_i}{\partial z} + \gamma \sum_{h=1}^\infty[f_h S_{i - h} \cos(\theta_{i-h} - \theta_i ) - f_h^* S_{i + h} \cos(\theta_{i + h} - \theta_i)] = 0
$$
where $\theta_i$ is given by the grating equation
$$
\sin \theta_i - \sin \theta = i K \lambda.
$$
Is it possible to solve this equation, or does it require a numerical calculation?
The component of the electric field parallel to the interface should be conserved, so I tried changing the phase-delay transmittance to
$$
\tau(x, z) = \exp[- 2 \pi j z d \Delta n \cos\theta / \lambda] \cos\theta
$$
and the transmittance in terms of the wave amplitudes to
$$
\tau(x, z) = \sum_{i=-\infty}^\infty S_i(z) \exp(j i \xi) \cos \theta_i
$$
such that the wave amplitudes become
$$
S_i(z) = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \frac{\cos \theta}{\cos \theta_i} \int_0^{2 \pi} \exp[-2 j \gamma z f(\xi)] \exp(-j i \xi) \, d\xi,
$$
but it doesn't solve the governing equation since I can see numerically that
$$
\frac{\cos \theta}{\cos \theta_i} \ne \frac{\cos \theta}{\cos \theta_{i-h}} \cos(\theta_{i-h} - \theta_i ).
$$
Any idea where I might be going wrong?

